# Varios selectores en JQuery en el evento Click como conozco el selector que realiza la acción

Tags: jquery

Paso varios selectores al evento click, pero me gustaría saber el selector que ha sido clickado.

**¿Como lo se?**

Ejemplo:

```
$("#selector1, #selector2").click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la solución y es:

```
let miSelector = "#"+this.id;
```